Getting "Method not allowed" in next js using API routes
Trying to use API routes in next js to call an api with POST method from server side, but getting "Method not allowed" error.
My page.tsx has a form; submitting the form must trigger handleSubmit function, which must call function in app/api/pinToIPFS/route.js, which will call POST method on API. I want API to be called on server side.
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import "../../globals.css";
import Link from "next/link";


function CreatePage() {

  const [form, setForm] = useState({ address: "", title: "", proposal: "" });


  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();


    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
      "file",
      new Blob([JSON.stringify(form)], { type: "application/json" })
    );

    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/pinToIPFS", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: formData,
      });

      const resData = await res.json();
      console.log("resData:", resData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
      alert("Trouble uploading file");
    }
  };

  return (
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      ></form>

and here is route.js in api/pinToIPFS/
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {

      const formData = req.body;


      const JWT = process.env.PINATA_JWT;
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${JWT}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: formData,
        }
      );


      const data = await response.json();

      res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error pinning file to IPFS:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Error pinning file to IPFS" });
    }
  } else {
    
    res.status(405).json({ error: "Method not allowed" });
  }
}


I am getting this error in console:
page.tsx:81       
POST http://localhost:3000/api/pinToIPFS 405 (Method Not Allowed)

page.tsx:94 
Error uploading file: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at handleSubmit (page.tsx:89:33)

Here are lines 80-97 in page.tsx:
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/pinToIPFS", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: formData,
      });

      const resData = await res.json();
      console.log("done!");

      console.log("resData:", resData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error uploading file:", error);
      alert("Trouble uploading file");
      setUploading(false);
    }

how to fix this?

Can you show the JSON you are trying to POST?

if you are using next.js v 13+, you need to export a function POST in route.js. find more about http export here

in route.ts function must have been called POST, and FormData should have been formed in route.ts, not page.tsx
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  console.log("ok, im in post");

  // Extract data from the request body

  const form = await new Response(req.body).json();
  console.log("this is form in post:", form);

  const JWT = process.env.PINATA_JWT;

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(
    "file",
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(form)], { type: "application/json" })
  );
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${JWT}`,
      },
      body: formData,
    }
  );

  // Handle the response from Pinata
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("this is original response:", response);
  console.log("pinata reponse:", data);

  // Respond with the data returned by Pinata
  return NextResponse.json(data, { status: 200 });
}

